# Copy angularjs expression result to clipboard on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to copy the result of this angular expression `{{ page.url }}` to clipboard on click. I have tried using ng-clipboard after I have installed this directive in my project but without any result.

```
<a ng-show="page.hovered" class="btn btn-warning bg-green-light btn-xs" ngclipboard data-clipboard="{{ page.url }}"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></a>
```

I don't know how to make this work. Any ideas would be great. I am new to angular, so any explanation would help me a lot! Thank you for your time!

Comment: <a ng-show="page.hovered" class="btn btn-warning bg-green-light btn-xs" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="{{ page.url }}"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></a>

Comment: tried it with no luck tho'

Comment: Can you post the code how you setup the module?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have added **ngclipboard** as dependency to your module

`angular.module('app', ['ngclipboard']);`

According to [Documentation](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/) there are no attribute *data-clipboard* but is ***data-clipboard-text***.

Working code:
`<a ng-show="page.hovered" class="btn btn-warning bg-green-light btn-xs" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="{{ page.url }}"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i></a>`

I have checked it here:
http://codepen.io/artemhp/pen/QGQjRY

Also be sure that you include ngclipboard.min.js after clipboard.min.js

Comment: For me, not even the code from codepen works... @artemhp

Comment: @Alphonse hello, sorry! In Codepen makes wrong ordering of scripts that is included in the header. I put them inside HTML and it's OK now. Please, check.